# thymeleaf error

Tags: thymeleaf

Below code throw error of unresolvable circular reference. when Spring is trying to create bean of MessageFormatHelper class.This error throw while I run the jar.  I try to see but not getting what is reason. Could anyone help.

First class,

```
@Component
class DbTemplateResolver extends TemplateResolver {
@Autowired 
SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine;
....othercode
@PostConstruct
    public void extension() {
        templateEngine.addTemplateResolver(this);
    }
...other code
}
```

Second class,

```
@Component
class MessageFormatHelper{

@Autowired
  SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine;
... other code
String getMessage()
{
        final Context ctx = new Context(locale);
                ctx.setVariable("contractMap", model.get(ContractMap.TEMPLATE_MODEL_MAP_KEY));
                mergedMessage = templateEngine.process(fileName, ctx);
}

}
```

Full error:

> > Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.flex.eventManagement.handler.helper.MessageFormatHelper com.flex.eventManagement.handler.helper.NotificationPreProcessor.messageFormatHelper; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'messageFormatHelper': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine com.flex.eventManagement.handler.helper.MessageFormatHelper.templateEngine; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.thymeleaf.ThymeleafAutoConfiguration$ThymeleafDefaultConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private final java.util.Collection org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.thymeleaf.ThymeleafAutoConfiguration$ThymeleafDefaultConfiguration.templateResolvers; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dbTemplateResolver': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine com.flex.eventManagement.handler.helper.DbTemplateResolver.templateEngine; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'templateEngine': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?

**Updated**
Remove template engine auto-wire from DbTemplateResolver class. Autowire into MessageFormatHelper.java class like below

```
class MessageFormatHelper{

 @Bean
  public DbTemplateResolver dbTemplateResolver() {
    DbTemplateResolver resolver = new DbTemplateResolver();
      resolver.setOrder(2);
      return resolver;
  }

  @Bean
  public SpringTemplateEngine thymeleafTemplateEngine() {
      SpringTemplateEngine engine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
      engine.setTemplateResolvers(Sets.newHashSet(dbTemplateResolver()));
      return engine;
  }
}
```

Also I need to remove SpringTemplateEngine auto wired from MessageFormatHelper right? so how can I call  `mergedMessage = templateEngine.process(fileName, ctx);?`

**Update 2.**
should followed required in **MessageFormatHelper**

```
  @Autowired
  DbTemplateResolver dbTemplateResolver;

  @Autowired
  SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine;
@PostConstruct
    public void extension() {
        templateEngine.addTemplateResolver(dbTemplateResolver);
    }
```

Comment: Ofcourse it will and it will never work like this... You are creating a `TemplateResolver`, which is needed to construct the `SpringTemplateEngine` but you expect it to be auto wired...So no it will never work. Just make the `DbResolver` a bean and configure it in a configuration lass and wire it to the `SpringTemplateEngine` instead of doing it like this. IMHO this is bad programming in the first place. If you are using Spring Boot you only need to declare the `DbResolver` as a bean and it will be automatically registered for you. Basically you are making it to complex.

Comment: You don't need those beans... Spring Boot already provides them for you... Understand the frameworks you are using and work WITH the framework. Remove the `@Bean` methods and simply `@Autowire` the template resolver in the `MessageFormatHelper` ... I never said you should change that!

Comment: No... As stated remove the `@Bean` methods, spring boot already configures the `SpringTempalteResolver` for you when it detects thyme leaf. The only thing you need to do is have a `@Bean` method for your custom `DbTemplateResolver` nothing more nothing less. In the classes you want to use the template resolver just auto wire the template resolver. Don't try to add configuration to it as that is already done.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is flawed and it seems you lack basic understanding of how Spring works and how you should use Spring to configure things.

First you are using Spring Boot and want to use Thymeleaf. This is simply done by added the `spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf` as a dependency for you project. (I assume you have already done this).

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf<artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Spring Boot detects the fact that you have Thymeleaf on your classpath and the [`ThymeleafAutoConfiguration`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/thymeleaf/ThymeleafAutoConfiguration.java) will kick in and configure the `SpringTemplateEngine` for you. It will even detect every bean of the type `ITemplateResolver`, which I assume your `DbTemplateResolver` implements.

The only thing to have your `DbTemplateResolver` add is to add a `@Bean` method to an `@Configuration` (or your application) class.

```
@Bean
public ITemplateResolver dbTemplateResolver() {
    return new DbTemplateResolver();
}
```

Spring will detect it and inject it into the automatically configured `SpringTemplateEngine`.

The only thing you need to do is in classes you need the `SpringTemplateEngine` you need to auto wire it. Just use the super class not the concrete type.

```
@Autowired
private TemplateEngine templateEngine;
```

Don't mess around with trying to configure it later on, use the framework for that.